# Glue dev endpoint - NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createStarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have created new package using Glue LPT option. I am running this scala code on Glue dev endpoint in glue-spark-shell. When I run basic query , it returns correct output

```
spark.sql("show databases").show
2020-01-15 22:42:56,070 WARN [main] client.NexusHiveMetaStore (NexusHiveMetaStore.java:getDatabases(101)) - GetDatabases by pattern currently unsupported- only "nexus" will be returned
+------------+
|databaseName|
+------------+
| nexus|
+------------+
```

When I am trying to run amother query, it says

```
spark.sql("select * from sivi.mbopCustomerData LIMIT 1”).show

scala> spark.sql("select * from sivi.mbopCustomerData LIMIT 1").show
2020-01-15 17:31:07,447 ERROR [main] metastore.RetryingHMSHandler (RetryingHMSHandler.java:invoke(159)) - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createStarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;
```

Not sure what is causing this problem.

Comment: Sounds like you are not making an uber jar

Comment: I am making uber jar

`
  <target name="build-superjar">
    <property name="superjar.out.dir" location="${bp:package-build-root}/packaging_additional_published_artifacts"/>
    <mkdir dir="${superjar.out.dir}"/>
    <superjar destfile="${superjar.out.dir}/${bp:package-name}-super.jar"
              classpath="${bp:run.classpath}:${bp:run.scalaclasspath.2.11}:${superjar.out.dir}/../Scala2.11/MBOPNexusReportGlue-1.0.jar"
              zip64Mode="always" />
  </target>
`

Comment: is that Ant? Can you please edit your question to format that better?